# Open multiple hyperlinks in default browser

Tags: vba, excel, google-chrome, hyperlink

Good afternoon, I am asking this because I didn't get any of the codes I got from the web working. I have a sheet that has a lot of links and I want to be able to open at least 10 of them at a time, in tabs. I previously had some code (that I lost) that opened all of them(in chrome), which was a big problem.
I would like 1 of 2 things:

Option 1: Open all the hyperlinks I select from a column in my default browser(chrome) (the hyperlinks are there with the following formula "=hyperlink(leftcell;"OPEN")

Option 2: I paste either the hyperlink or text in another sheet and the 10 first rows are opened.

I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: If you show us the code that you are trying to get to work, and tell us what it isn't doing correctly, we might be better able to help you fix it than if we just have to guess what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to call the `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink` function, and use the links you already have in your worksheet.
Assuming you have the links in the form bellow:

[Links in worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR273.png)

You now have to loop in these links and open them one by one. In the bellow code the column A is hard coded, but you can easily change that by another input of yours, like a user selection, for example.

```
Sub test_link()

Dim current_row As Integer
Dim last_row As Integer
Dim current_sht As Worksheet

current_row = 1
Set current_sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
last_row = current_sht.Cells(current_sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

While current_row <= last_row
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=current_sht.Range("A" & current_row) 'Open link
    current_row = current_row + 1
Wend
```

End Sub

Comment: Maybe I could modify it to open just a selection but as I don't know how to do it I will use it as it is. Thank you very much. I surely appreciate the time you are going to free me.